# Keeping track of SKNodes for a category

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a function that adds enemies to my scene that get called by an timing interval

How can I keep track of the number of enemies on the Scene to limit the amount of enemies I have in each level?

**In my update function **

```
CFTimeInterval timeSinceLastEnemy = currentTime - self.lastEnemyUpdateTime;
self.lastEnemyUpdateTime = currentTime;
if (timeSinceLastEnemy > 1) { // more than a second since last update
    timeSinceLastEnemy = 1.0 / 60.0;
    self.lastEnemyUpdateTime = currentTime;
}

[self spwanEnemyWithTime:timeSinceLastEnemy];
```

**The timer and The method to add enemies **

```
- (void)spwanEnemyWithTime:(CFTimeInterval)timeSinceLast {

    self.lastEnemySpawn += timeSinceLast;
    if (self.lastEnemySpawn > 0.6) {
        self.lastEnemySpawn = 0;
        [self spawnEnemy];
    }
}

-(void) spawnEnemy {

    SKSpriteNode *enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: enemySprite];

    int minX = 5;
    int maxX = self.frame.size.width;
    int rangeX = maxX - minX;
    int actualX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;

    // Create the enemy slightly off-screen along the upper edge,

    enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(enemy.size.height - 10 , enemy.size.width)]; 
    enemy.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory; 
    enemy.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = bulletCategory; 
    enemy.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;     

    // and along a random position along the X axis as calculated above
    enemy.position = CGPointMake(actualX, self.frame.size.height + enemy.size.height);
    [self addChild:enemy];
    enemy.xScale = 0.2;
    enemy.yScale = 0.2;
    enemy.zPosition = 4;

    // Create the actions
    SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveToY:(0 - enemy.size.height) duration:4];
    SKAction * actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    [enemy runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove, actionMoveDone]]];
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? show us the code where you add the enemies. show us the code for your timer. You need to supply enough information for people to help you, or you will get flagged as "too Broad".

Comment: welcome to SO, please see https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/

Comment: @RonMyschuk I have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confess I couldn't grasp what you are doing with the double timers, so I will assume that portion works as you want it to. for the enemy count couldn't this be as simple as incrementing a counter on your spawnEnemy and decrementing the counter when the enemy removes itself from the scene?

You'll have to double check my Obj-c I haven't used it in a while.

```
int enemyCount = 0;

-(void) spawnEnemy {

    enemyCount += 1

    ...

    // Create the actions
    SKAction *actionMove = [SKAction moveToY:(0 - enemy.size.height) duration:4];
    SKAction *actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    SKAction *decrementCount = [SKAction runBlock: ^(void) {
        enemyCount -= 1;                           
    }];

    [enemy runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove, actionMoveDone, decrementCount]]];
}
```

FYI you have a typo in your method "spwanEnemyWithTime"